# Unable to hide custom columns in Discussion Board

Tags: 2013, column, discussion-board

I have added some custom fields to a Discussion Board list in SP 2013 that are populated using Workflow. I do not want these to appear in any of the create or edit item views.

I have marked the items as Hidden in the Settings: List Content Type but they are still showing in the NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx views.

Any ideas how to fix this?

UPDATE:
Here is a view of what I have set the columns to in list content type;
[image]

And here is how it is being displayed despite marking them as Hidden;
[image]

Comment: Did you mark then hidden in 'Discussion' Content type ?

Comment: @BhaskarDhone I don't appear to have permissions for the Discussion content type only the local instance of the list. I have added these custom columns to my local instance and with all other list objects, marking them as hidden works perfectly. It does appear to be a problem with the Discussion Board list.

Comment: Yes , I was talking about 'Discussion' content type of list only. This works when you mark them as hidden. Tested in my env.

Comment: I've edited my post above - as you can see I have set the custom columns to Hidden as you describe but they are still not being hidden in the NewForm.aspx

Comment: I can see they are hidden in 'Message'Content type of list. Are they hidden in 'Discussion' content type of list as well ?

Comment: I think I need my eyes testing. I hadn't spotted that there were 2 content types - having only ever seen one in normal lists. All fixed now - thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82860/discussion-between-bhaskar-dhone-and-unibod50).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discussion board has two content type. **Discussion** and **Message** You need to mark them as hidden in '**Discussion**' Content type of list if you do not those fields in form on **'New Discussion'** and mark then hidden in '**Message**' content type if you do not want then in message i.e  reply of discussion.